# How to compare values in Cells A3:A25 with H3:25 and print them in another sheet if matches are found?

Tags: google-sheets

I have [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OuzzhUMlQ2KhYRhxmBmammjTQLMEPBsDP5sDyKyrfeo/edit?usp=sharing) with some values.

I need to compare values in Cells A3 to A25 with those of H3 to H25 and whenever a match is found, that match is to be copied and pasted to another column, say, F3 to F10.

Comment: How to do this you have multiple occurrences as TVSMOTOR! can you explain and give the expected output?

Comment: You can consider the first occurrence of each value and ignore the subsequent occurrences of the same value. Expected output is unique, non-repeated values which are present in both Column A and H

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of matchning items by

```
=sort(unique(arrayformula(vlookup((MATCH(Sell!A3:A,Sell!H3:H,0)),{row(Sell!H:H),Sell!H:H},2,0))))
```

Comment: Hi Mike! thanks for the help but it didn't give desired output.